# How to emulate this aesthetic using Photoshop or Gimp

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, color-conversion

I would like to replicate the style used in these images. I can tell it's not just good photography, but the images are also edited. What I wanna do is take an image that has a white background, change the colors and then do whatever it is they do to make it look crisp.

Sample raw image:

[image]

Style I am after:

[image]

[image]

- Here you can tell there has been lots of manipulation

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by crisp?

Comment: *How* can you "tell it's not just good photography"? -- It *could* be 3D renders.... or individual isolated photographs. *Many* of the shadows are added after the fact, because they rarely, if ever, actually correspond with lighting on the objects themselves.

Comment: @Vikas the images with colored backgrounds: The backgrounds have a gradient, but are super smooth. Even a very flat surface would have some imperfections, like in the raw image. That's what I want

Comment: @Scott the socks with the cup would be too difficult to render realistically. These are retouched images

Comment: I dont see how they need to have some effect on them all you need is some subtle over exposure. But also they dont all necceserily represent same method. They could be a mixture of photograpsh and renders. Also i disagee that the sock couldnt be a 3D render. It could but probably is not. It looks most likely to be a photograph which is slightly too exposed at photography time.

Comment: The socks, specifically, looks like 1 sock duplicated.

Comment: @Scott I observed socks closely. Both look different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can manage taking high quality photos in this (the way your examples are shown) kind of layout and good light, you can use selection tools and *manual shadows* in Photoshop:

1. Take photo of the products
2. Select the products (discarding shadows) using pen tool (I prefer) and paste them in new layers <kbd>Cntl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
3. Separately draw shapes for the shadows, each in new layers
4. Convert the shadow layers to smart object and lower opacities (in general, the more bright is the light, more opaque should be the shadow. I have kept them at 70% opacity to make them more realistic) and blur them a bit.
5. Add additional Drop Shadow (You can do this using Blending Options) for each product and later convert the shadow effect into raster layers using `Layer > Layer Style > Create Layer`. And mask the unnecessary shadow.
6. Hide the unnecessary remaining photo areas. Add a solid background of your choice.
7. Adjust overall color/temperature/brightness of the composition if you want.

Here's the progress:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that it is still highly dependent on the quality of the photos.